# How to get the configuration type of a project in intelliJIdea plugin?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

So, I need to get the configuration name of a current project, for example, I need to know is this angular project or android one.
I need something like:

```
getCurProject().getConfiguration().getType().getName();
```

Comment: There is no such distinction in IntelliJ IDEA. A single project, or even a single module in a project, can contain both Android and Angular code, and the respective IDE features will work with that code. Therefore, the API you're looking for does not exist. If you can explain what you're trying to accomplish, we can provide suggestions how to do that.

Comment: So, for example, I have a typescript file, and I wanna know is this typescript file related to angular or vue.